# How is inline style added to HTML elements by Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, highcharts

I am using the Highcharts library to create diagrams. I have two seemingly very similar charts that don't behave the same in terms of CSS for reasons I am trying to find out.

One thing I observed is that for example the menu items of an export button within these two charts have different code (extracted with Chrome Dev Tools).

The chart that 'behaves' in general as expected in terms of styling has this element code:

```
<div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Download PDF document</div>
```

The chart that does not 'react' when I change styles has for the same menu item this element code:

```
<div class="highcharts-menu-item">Download PDF document</div>
```

So the inline style is missing. When I am trying to search inline style code of the first element given, e.g. 'background: none;' I get no results for my whole project. So I assume that the Highcharts library is responsible for adding these inline styles with some JavaScript.

What could be reasons that this is done in the first element given and not in the second one?

Some explanation on how this mechanism obviously used by the library works, would be very helpful for my understanding on what is going on.

PS: I am using the React wrapper in case this has any relevance:

```
<HighchartsReact
  highcharts={ Highcharts }
  constructorType={"stockChart"}
  options={chartOptions}
  ref="chartComponent"
  allowChartUpdate={this.allowChartUpdate}
/>
```

Edit: I am using styled mode. In this case it is necessary to write CSS rules using the classes defined by highcharts, e.g. .highcharts-title but still I need to write !important like here

```
font-size: 22px !important;
```

so that this font-size supersedes the 'infused' styles as described above (although there is no style attribute given in the chartOptions (which I think would anyway be superseded by CSS rules).

Comment: Have you already seen the documentation about styling via CSS? It should help you to understand more about styling in Highcharts. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

Answer (score 0):

There is on props i.e. `containerProps` which needs class name (I think).

So what I suggest is create a css-class in your css file and pass that class name to that prop like this:

```
containerProps = {{ className: 'chartContainer' }}
```

You can read more about this from [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#user-content-options-details)